# Find out probability to win a game

Tags: probability, probability-theory, game-theory

Let's suppose we have a button that indicates a random number from 1 to 30 (including 1 and 30). There are 30 people who play the game, only one person wins.

Game rules A: Each person is enumerated from 1 to 30, the button is pressed once. The one whose number is rolled wins the game.

Game rules B: Each person pushes the button. The one who gets the highest number wins. If two or more people get the same largest number, they play among themselves and press the button again until one of them gets the highest number.

It is clear for me that for game rules A probability to win is 1/30 or 3%.
What is probability to win the game using game rules B, is it 1/30 as well?

Comment: Yes, clearly, because there is no bias towards one player compared to another so they should have equal chances of winning.  The only noticeable difference between the games is the expected amount of time and possible amount of time that each game would last.  The game always ends after a single press of a button for game A but it is possible that game B could last several presses of a button.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you for the answer! Do you think the possible outcomes would be the same for both games? One of my calculations included the classic probability formula, and I had different possible and desired outcomes, but It seems that I was wrong...

Comment: I don't follow your question.  You can describe your outcomes however you like.  If you choose to describe your outcome simply by who won in the end, you may do so.  If you do that for both A and B, the outcomes are identical.  If you choose to describe your outcome as the result of each player's interactions with one another, then B may have outcomes that look differently, but when aggregated will simplify down to what it was for A.

Comment: (1) If you can show us what you did for B, in which you get a "wrong answer", maybe then we can help you find where it went wrong.  (2) The case for B is simply (i) each of $30$ people has equal prob to win, and (ii) the prob that _someone_ will win is $1$. Together (i) & (ii) implies the answer is $1/30$. While (i) is obvious (by symmetry), you can either say (ii) is also obvious, or try to prove it. Proving it using basic arithmetic would require writing out some infinite sums and showing they converge to $1$... which is not so trivial actually. So I hope you also find (ii) obvious! :)